# Google maps отметки по координатам

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте, хочу реализовать вот такую вещь.  В базе данных есть координата каждого пользователя(место в градусах, где он находится). Подскажите (или расскажите, чем воспользоваться, может плагин есть какой-нибудь jquery) как сделать так, что бы они появились на карте google, которая встроена как отметки? (Что-то подобное находиться в Vk. com, только там выводятся фотографии). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "на карте google которая встроена как отметки " - это как?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Maps Javascript API V3 Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=ru). Думаю, что это вам пригодится